# Firebase Services not working with Firebase Test Lab devices due to the APK is being re-sign

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config, firebase-test-lab

I am doing a test with Firebase Test Lab but the emulator cannot continue most likely due to having problem with Firebase SDK. The app cannot continue after the splash screen because it need Remote Config to fetch successfully if failed then AlertDialog is shown.

[image]

Error log from Test Lab

[image]

[image]

[image]

I checked the app-debug.apk SHA and it was the same as what is registered in the Firebase project and Cloud console and I can run it locally on my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Roboscript fails because the app fails to start properly and thus, Roboscript cannot perform its actions.

If Remote Config fails to fetch due to your app's APK being re-signed, then you can make Robo try to crawl your app without re-signing the APK by making sure that your app stops when Remote Config fails to fetch without any additional dialogs (shown in your crawl graph). In FTL, when Robo detects that an app could not be crawled after being re-signed, it will attempt to crawl it without re-signing.

Comment: Yes the question I have now would be, how can I use Robo script without it re-signing the APK? I am using Test Lab with GCloud CLI as well but not sure if it is stated in the documentation about adding a flag to skip re-signing of APK.

Comment: Cannot skip the fetch of Remote Config part because it has something to do for the app to work completely, also even we skip Remote Config and remove the dialog other Firebase services will be rendered useless since the app has different signing configuration.

Comment: Is this the current limit of using Firebase Test Lab with Robo? We need to know so we can move on. Thanks

Comment: As of now, the flag to skip re-signing an APK is not exposed in Firebase Console or the gcloud CLI. We are looking into making this flag available soon. In the meanwhile, you can tweak your app a bit to make Robo try to crawl it without re-signing the APK. To achieve this, you do NOT need to remove the Remote Config part, you just need to make sure that when it fails to fetch, there are no buttons for Robo to interact with (like in the warning dialog). For example, you could check that fetching failed and crash your app right away, so no dialog is shown.

Comment: So there will be an option on the next update where re-signing the APK can be omitted, that's really important. Is there a said timeline for this? For now we can't really go with your suggestion since we are in a CI CD environment and we wanted to test the app just like in a true production scenario and use cases then automatically publish it on the store. I hope that is enough reason why the suggestion above will not work for everyone. Thank you

Comment: The option to avoid re-signing the APK will be publicly accessible in our API in about a week. Depending on your CI setup, it might take some additional time to update the clients, if any. Do you mind expanding a bit on your CI setup? Do you use our API or gcloud directly or some other tools? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for late reply,  currently using Bitbucket Pipelines with GCloud CLI to access Firebase Test LabI. So far it seems working fine we can use command like `gcloud firebase test android models list` and `gcloud beta firebase test android run testlab_first_robo_test.yml:args` the remaining problem would probably be this apk re-signing issue. Regarding this upcoming update of option, we can still use our own Robo script not just the default crawler correct?

Comment: Thank you for the details! So, we would also need to update gcloud to add an argument that will allow you to specify that you do not want Robo to re-sign your APK (and change testlab_first_robo_test.yml:args accordingly). You should still be able to use a Roboscript when an APK is not re-signed, but please note that Roboscript recorded in Android Studio is for the scenario when Robo re-signs the app's APK and crawls it in Espresso mode, while not re-signing the app's APK means that Robo crawls it in UIAutomator mode, which might or might not require some manual tweaking of your Roboscript.

Comment: So even after the update we can't use our Robo script without re-signing the APK is this correct? Thus we can only use the default Robo crawler that has option to skip re-signing.

Comment: I also noticed that you will get same behavior in Pre-Launch report in Google Play Console

Comment: You should be able to use your Roboscript when your app's APK is not re-signed, but it might require some tweaking. And yeah, you see the same behavior in Play Pre-Launch Report because it uses FTL to perform Robo crawls.

Comment: What kind of tweaking, can you give some example scenario? Thank you

Comment: It depends on the structure of your app and actions/target elements in your Roboscript. For example, if one of your Roboscript actions clicks an item of a RecyclerView, it might need adjustment, since Robo does not distinguish RecyclerViews in UIAutomator mode.

Comment: I saw that it can record clicks on Recyclerview with a given index but no recording when scrolling through list

Comment: There is one last thing that I think needs to be change as well with Firebase Test Lab when using it with GCloud CLI. Uploading APK is already a bit long depending on your app size but the main problem is the CLI also waits for the test result which is very long and will take up more build minutes in the pipeline which is kinda expensive. Probably it would be nice as well to have an option to skip the test result and check it in the Firebase Console page itself instead in the pipeline.

Comment: Recording scrolling through RecyclerView items is not necessary as recording the index of the clicked element is sufficient to scroll to this element and click it when Roboscript is executed.

Comment: When can we expect this new API flag? Also will this be available in Pre-Launch report because we think it should be right?

Comment: Depending on gcloud release schedule, it should be out within a couple of weeks. As for Play Pre-Launch Report, there should already be this option somewhere on the settings page (where you can upload a Roboscript, etc.).

Comment: Thanks by the way there still no option on Play Pre-Launch Report.

Comment: Play Pre-Launch Report used to have this option for a long time, but it appears that they removed it after a recent UI update.

Comment: By the way, to avoid gcloud waiting for the test results, you can use --async flag.

Comment: Great! Will try that one. Thanks a lot! Excited and happy for the upcoming update skipping re-signing of APK.

Comment: Its finally here! `Added --resign flag to gcloud beta firebase test android run. This flag allows clients to specify if Robo should re-sign the app-under-test APK.` how should we use it? This statement makes me assumed that by default Robo will no longer resign the test apk.

Comment: I was about to inform you that the new feature got out as part of gcloud beta, but then I saw that you found it yourself already :) Yeah, please use --no-resign to disable re-signing, since Robo keeps re-signing by default if no argument is provided.

Comment: When can we expect this option in the console as well? Currently our Robo Script always fail at the beginning and does not follow the instruction correctly, thus tweaking the script will always be inevitable. With that case, we may need to optimize the each Robo Script first on the Firebase console manually then use the GCloud CLI when it is already working properly. The idea is to avoid repetitive use of build minute in CI CD during testing with Robo Script

Comment: Adding this option to the console is on our roadmap, but there is no specific timeline for that yet. In the meanwhile, to tune your Roboscripts, you might consider running Robo (App Crawler) locally https://developer.android.com/training/testing/crawler. You can use --robo-script-file <path> command line option to specify your Roboscript for a local run.

Comment: Many thanks, I do have new update question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/68581903/12204620

Answer (score 1):

The likely problem here is that Robo generally must re-sign your app before running your test in FTL.

There's a new feature in the Testing API that let's you set the Robo test mode to ROBO_VERSION_1, which will run Robo in UIAutomator-only mode without resigning the app. Unfortunately that feature is not exposed yet in the Firebase Console or the `gcloud` CLI.

Comment: Thanks, so what is the solution for this? I think they never mention that in the documentation explaining Firebase Robo test re-sign the app and can't really recall it but before I think it works without further action.