# Firebase Robo Test Script keeps failing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

We are using Firebase UI with Phone Auth and it seems Robo Script does not work properly with it. Device like LG Nexus 5, API Level 23 hammerhead works fine following some part of the script but many other physical devices we tried failed following the script.

This is a success OTP with Firebase Auth with LG Nexus 5

[image]

This one is totally incorrect at the very beginning Samsung SM-G981U1
[image]

And the list of non-working physical device with Robo script goes on, not sure what is special about Nexus 5 or probably it has something to do with the screen resolution? One thing I noticed is after putting `9876543210` in `EditText` of Firebase UI phone Auth the test device with Robo Script always fails to click `Verify Phone Number` button where most likely the error occurred except for LG Nexus 5 which successfully execute this part of the script.

Another sample

[image]

Here it supposed to hit `Verify Phone Number` button after successfully putting `9876543210` in EditText which is based on our Robo Script but it didn't and the whole input was replaced with `6504992804` which we never record and not in Robo Script. So our conclusion was the error usually happens due to failure of script satisfying the click of `Verify Phone Number` button.

[image]

Robo Script sample

```
[
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1627584568123,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 7000,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
    "timestamp": 1627584581148,
    "replacementText": "9876543210",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": true,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "com.devsbitwise.cryptonian:id/phone_number",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.FrameLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "com.devsbitwise.cryptonian:id/phone_layout",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
    "timestamp": 1627584599899,
    "replacementText": "Verify Phone Number",
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 0,
    "canScrollTo": true,
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "className": "com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
        "resourceId": "com.devsbitwise.cryptonian:id/send_code",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": "Verify Phone Number"
      },
      {
        "className": "androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
        "resourceId": "",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      },
      {
        "className": "android.widget.ScrollView",
        "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
        "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
        "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
        "resourceId": "",
        "contentDescription": "",
        "text": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1627584605228,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 500,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
  },
```

**UPDATE**

Last remaining problem is probably the consistency, here I used the same Robo script in first test it succeed but in the second with no changes in the code at all it fails.

First Test (Nexus 5 Virtual SDK 21)
[image]

Second Test (Nexus 5 Virtual SDK 21)
[image]

First Test (Nexus 9 Virtual SDK 24)
[image]

Second Test (Nexus 9 Virtual SDK 24)
[image]

First Test (Nexus 7 Virtual SDK 22)
[image]

Second Test (Nexus 7 Virtual SDK 22)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that Roboscript fails to click the `Verify Phone Number` button, as the result says that Roboscript failed on action 3, which is clicking this button.

Overall, I think the problem might be more related to the API level rather than a specific physical (or virtual) device and the difference in API levels between the device on which you recorded your Roboscript and the device on which you perform it. The best way to overcome any discrepancies is to simplify your Roboscript as much as possible. For example, as long as your target elements have unique identifying attributes (e.g., resource id, text, etc.), you can use just those to identify them, like this:

```
[
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "delayTime": 7000
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
    "replacementText": "9876543210",
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "resourceId": "com.devsbitwise.cryptonian:id/phone_number"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
    "elementDescriptors": [
      {
        "resourceId": "com.devsbitwise.cryptonian:id/send_code"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "delayTime": 500
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, does this sample itself should work?

Comment: I tried to simplify it like what is in the above sample but still only LG Nexus 5 hammerhead works with Firebase Auth OTP among many physical devices that I tested.

Comment: Does Roboscript fail at the same action as before (i.e., not clicking the `Verify Phone Number` button)?

Comment: Yes same issue like before

Comment: Hmm, this is very strange, because it would imply that there is no enabled visible widget with resource id "com.devsbitwise.cryptonian:id/send_code" on the screen at the moment when Roboscript tries to perform this click action. To troubleshoot further, you might replace "resourceId": "com.devsbitwise.cryptonian:id/send_code" with "text": "Verify Phone Number" for this click action and/or add a delay ("DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED") before this click action (in case, the screen needs some time to stabilize).

Comment: Don't we have this `"resourceId": "com.devsbitwise.cryptonian:id/send_code" with "text": "Verify Phone Number"` in the sample script above? Sorry I understand little of this script and I might be wrong.

Comment: I was referring to the simplified Roboscript sample from my reply, which uses only `"resourceId": "com.devsbitwise.cryptonian:id/send_code"`, which I suggested to replace with `"text": "Verify Phone Number"`, so only `"text"` identifying attribute is used in the resulting Roboscript to match the target element. Having both `"resourceId"` and `"text"`, as in your original Roboscript, makes Robo try to find a target element that matches both these identifying attributes (in addition to other identifying attributes present in your original Roboscript, e.g., `"groupViewChildPosition"`).

Comment: Don't we have a option on Firebase Assistant to do a simplified Robo Script recording or at least we can configure which attributes to include in the script since the default one that has many attributes is not really working on many device. It seems that the current Robo Script is not yet ready for production even with simple navigation as it doesn't work across devices. If the script has a hundred of action even if it is simple navigation, doing manual simplification of the script is really time consuming and prone to human error WDYT?

Comment: I also noticed that the Robo Script in Test Lab fails to follow on clicking the correct item from Toolbar Menu items

Comment: You can tweak what is used in a recorded Roboscript on File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment [-> Testing] -> Espresso Test Recorder, where you can reduce max UI depth to 1, make it not use 'text' and/or 'content description' attributes and so on.

Comment: Usually, Roboscripts work fine across different devices and API levels, so if you are curious, you might investigate more why this is not the case for your app (for example, by recording an Espresso Test with the same actions using Espresso Test Recorder in Android Studio and looking at why it fails on different devices/emulators). One of the contributing factors might be that you run your Robo crawls in UIAutomator mode (i.e., without the app-under-test APK re-signing), which is not a common scenario.

Comment: We add the `--no-resign` in GCloud CLI implemented in our CI CD, is that what you are referring as another possible cause?

Comment: Yes, so this consideration would apply only when you use Roboscript in your CI environment with --no-resign flag.

Comment: I tried to tweak  Espresso Test Recorder from the settings but the generated script looks the same as before. You said that the issue comes with UIAutomator with APK re-signing part removed, this is the current limitation rather than intended implementation correct? Cause it would be really great if
*We can record and create a simple UI test script.
*Test and upload the app that has Firebase services with GCloud CLI in CI CD. Since the app uses Firebase services, it is important to keep the original signing so that developer would not need to register new SHAs again and again on each test.

Comment: I mean the first reason why we have "Record Robo Test" feature is for it to serve as instructions for our Test Lab tests and if testing with UIAutomator mode is the problem here then it is counter-intuitive and defeat its whole purpose. My understanding is when you provide a script in Test Lab it means you will be in UIAutomator mode and this is different from the default crawler.

Comment: Don't you get fewer element descriptors in the generated Roboscript when you reduce max UI depth to 1? You can also double check the effect of this settings change using Espresso Test Recorder (Run -> Record Espresso Test from the main menu).

Comment: Providing a Roboscript in Test Lab does not imply that Robo will crawl your app in UIAutomator mode. Using `--no-resign` gcloud flag does. The issue here comes from the specifics of your app, while running the crawl in UIAutomator mode might only be an additional contributing factor. So, to get to the bottom of it, if you are interested, I would suggest to play with the small Roboscript I presented above: tweak it gradually and check the effect (for example, using `"text"` instead of `"resourceId"` to identify the `Verify Phone Number` button).

Comment: The generated Roboscript is the same even reducing the max UI depth = 1, scrollview detection depth = 5, assertion depth = 3, checked Limit max depth to identifiable elements

Comment: I wonder if this could be due to Android Studio using the stale value for the updated settings parameter. Do you mind changing max UI depth to 1, saving your Settings, then restarting Android Studio and checking if it has any effect? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any possibility for the Firebase console to have the skip resigning feature so we can optimize the script much easier before integrating it within CI/CD?

Comment: Skipping re-signing of the app-under-test APK is an advanced feature, so it is lower priority among the features we are working on for the Firebase console. Why don't you use gcloud directly (rather than as part of CI/CD) to optimize your Roboscript? If you like, you can still use Firebase console to see your test run results when it is triggered via gcloud.

Comment: Yes, I tried to optimize and test it again with 8 device and somehow 6 of them works. Either I replace these devices that fails or optimize the script further. One thing that I think should be remove on test devices is the "Nearby Share" app since when a test app has sharing feature/intent and the Robo crawler reach that "Nearby Share", it spent all its time on that and get stuck thus wasting the runtime as well.

Comment: Can you explain as well my updates? It seems that there is a time where Robo script fails even it succeeded the same test before.

Comment: What can we possibly do on those inconsistency?

Comment: There is a level of nondeterminism in what actions Robo picks to perform as well as in the crawled app itself. Although Roboscript is intended to make a crawl more deterministic, some of its features (e.g., postponing or skipping actions whose UI targets are missing on a screen) might still lead to nondeterministic outcomes due to Robo and app-under-crawl nondeterministic behavior. To get a better understanding of what is going on, I would suggest to identify what Roboscript action fails in the failed runs and check whether the same action fails consistently across different runs and devices.